# How to prove $ \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^{n+k}{n+k\choose n-k}}{2k+1}=\frac{-2\cos\left(\frac{2(n-1)\pi}{3}\right)}{2n+1}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, fibonacci-numbers

How to prove

$$\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n+k}{n-k}\frac{(-1)^{n+k}}{2k+1}=-\frac{2}{2n+1}\,\cos\left(\frac{2(n-1)\pi}{3}\right)\;\text{?}$$

I have a proof by induction for it, but it isn't simple! I want to seek an interesting proof for it. (Sorry for my English study is very bad)
Can you help me re-open this question?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Very nice identity.

Comment: What is the point in closing interesting questions, even after they have been answered? I voted for reopening. This kind of questions, also without efforts from the OP, make MSE a resourceful place, they deserve to stay open, IMHO.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Relevan discussion on meta: [Why close old questions with accepted answers using the "no context" reason?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19377/why-close-old-questions-with-accepted-answers-using-the-no-context-reason)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

We may exploit:
$$ F_{2n+1}(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n+k}{n-k}x^{2k}\tag{1} $$
where $F_n(x)$ is a [Fibonacci polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_polynomials). That gives:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n+k}{n-k}\frac{(-1)^{n+k}}{2k+1}=(-1)^n\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\alpha(x)^{2n+1}-\beta(x)^{2n+1}}{\alpha(x)-\beta(x)}\,dx,\tag{2}$$
where:
$$ \alpha(x) = \frac{ix+\sqrt{4-x^2}}{2},\qquad \beta(x) = \frac{ix-\sqrt{4-x^2}}{2},\tag{3}$$
so we just need to use the substitution $x=2\sin\theta$ in the RHS of $(2)$ to prove our claim, since the RHS of $(2)$ is so converted into:
$$ 2(-1)^n \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{6}}\cos((2n+1)\theta)\,d\theta.\tag{4}$$
As pointed by r9m, the same can be achieved by using Chebyshev polynomials of the second kind in the first place.

Comment: @jackd'aurizo just curious ... How does the term "$(-1)^k$" appear in the sum $(2)$ after integrating $(1)$ from $0$ to $1$.

Comment: @Dr.MV: you just need to take $F_{2n+1}(\color{red}{i} x)$ to make a $(-1)^k$ appear in the RHS of $(1)$.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm reading on an I-phone and missed the $i$ in the $\alpha$ and $\beta$ terms.  Apology.

Comment: @Dr.MV: no problem :)

Comment: Very nice solution! :)

Comment: (+1) I had never seen Fibonacci polynomials used before. Perhaps I should add them to my toolbox.

Comment: @robjohn: a (+1) of yours is always a heavyweight (+1), I am glad you enjoyed my solution.

Comment: (+1)ed! :-) Nice Fibonacci Polynomial approach! I used Chebyshev Polynomial of $2^{nd}$ kind.

Answer (score 15):

Let's try a generating function approach.

Multiply by $x^ky^n$ and sum in both $k$ and $n$:
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k,n}\binom{n+k}{n-k}x^ky^n
&=\sum_{k,n}\binom{n}{2k}\frac{x^k}{y^k}y^n\tag{1}\\
&=\frac1{1-y}\sum_k\frac{x^ky^k}{(1-y)^{2k}}\tag{2}\\
&=\frac{1-y}{(1-y)^2-xy}\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: $\binom{n+k}{n-k}=\binom{n+k}{2k}$, then substitute $n\mapsto n-k$
$(2)$: $\sum\limits_n\binom{n}{k}x^n=\frac{x^k}{(1-x)^{k+1}}$
$(3)$: $\sum\limits_kx^k=\frac1{1-x}$

Substitute $x\mapsto-x^2$, $y\mapsto y^2$ and integrate $(3)$ in $x$ from $0$ to $1$:
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k,n}\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}\binom{n+k}{n-k}y^{2n}
&=\int_0^1\frac{1-y^2}{(1-y^2)^2+x^2y^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{4}\\
&=\frac1y\,\tan^{-1}\!\left(\frac{y}{1-y^2}\right)\tag{5}\\[6pt]
&=\frac1y\left[\tan^{-1}\left(e^{i\pi/3}y\right)+\tan^{-1}\left(e^{-i\pi/3}y\right)\right]\tag{6}\\
&=2\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}\cos\left(\frac{(2n+1)\pi}3\right)y^{2n}\tag{7}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(4)$: substitute $x\mapsto-x^2$, $y\mapsto y^2$ and integrate $(3)$ in $x$ from $0$ to $1$
$(5)$: perform the integration
$(6)$: use the formula for tangent of a sum
$(7)$: use the series for arctangent

Equation $(7)$ implies that
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(-1)^{n+k}}{2k+1}\binom{n+k}{n-k}
&=\frac2{2n+1}\cos\left(\frac{(2n+1)\pi}3\right)\tag{8}\\
&=-\frac2{2n+1}\cos\left(\frac{(2n-2)\pi}3\right)\tag{9}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(8)$: equate identical powers of $y$ in $(7)$
$(9)$: $\cos(x+\pi)=-\cos(x)$

Comment: I sort of prefer $(8)$ to $(9)$; there is no minus sign and the $2n+1$ in the argument to cosine matches that in the denominator.

Comment: (+1) in return, since your solution is very instructive, too.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: I can't help feeling that there must be some simple, elementary method (not using complex variables) to get this identity. I will continue looking for one.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment?

Comment: Random downvotes strike you too, @robjohn? I am becoming used to them, but I agree that a random downvote + no comment is a really upsetting situation here on MSE.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: all the time.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: I know there is nothing wrong with most of the answers that are downvoted (there is an occasional downvote that is deserved and I try to fix those answers), so it doesn't bother me too much. I only worry that something might need to be more clearly explained for someone. However, if they don't leave a comment, I can't help them.

Answer (score 15):

**My Solution**

We have: \begin{align*}\sum_{k=0}^n\dfrac{(-1)^{n+k}}{2k+1}{n+k\choose n-k}&=\sum_{k=0}^n \dfrac{(-1)^{n+k}(n+k)!}{(2k+1)!(n-k)!} \\ &=\dfrac{1}{2n+1}\sum_{k=0}^n\dfrac{(-1)^{n+k}(n+k)!\left[(n+k+1)+(n-k)\right]}{(2k+1)!(n-k)!}\\&=\dfrac{1}{2n+1}\sum_{k=0}^n\left[(-1)^{n+k}{n+1+k\choose 2k+1} -(-1)^{n-1+k}{n+k\choose 2k+1}\right]\\ &=\dfrac{1}{2n+1}\left(S_n-S_{n-1}\right)\end{align*}
Where: \begin{align*}S_n&=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n+k}{n+1+k\choose 2k+1}=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n+k}{n+1+k\choose n-k}\\ &=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k{2n+1-k\choose k}\qquad\text{(reverse index)}\end{align*}
So, easy proof $\quad S_n=-S_{n-1}-S_{n-2}\quad$ [(reference here)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/936864/calculate-the-binomial-sum-i-n-sum-i-0n-1i-2n1-i-choose-i?rq=1)

$\{S_n\}_{n\ge 0}\;:\;\{1,-1,0,1,-1,0,1,-1,0,...\}$

$\{S_n-S_{n-1}\}_{n\ge 1}\;:\;\{-2,1,1,-2,1,1,-2,1,1,...\}$

DONE! :D

Comment: Hey! That's a really nice proof!!! :D (+1) I had forgotten about the periodicity of $S_n$!! Awesome find!

Comment: (+1) Nice answer! I had that very $S_n$ in my notes, but never realized that it was periodic.

Comment: Thanks for all :)

Comment: Nice solution (+1)! No trigonometry required.   I did notice that RHS is equal to $\Re \left(-\frac 2{2n+1}\omega^{n-1}\right)$, so perhaps there might be a proof which uses this. Also, for $n=1,2,3,...$, the "series" is $-\frac 33+\frac 13, \frac 15, \frac 17, -\frac 39+\frac 19,\frac 1{11},\frac 1{13},...$, and the last term in the expansion is also $\frac 13, \frac 15, \frac 17, ...$. Hence, if we can show that the sum $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}$ is $-\frac 3{2n+1}$ for $n=4, 7, 11,...$ and zero otherwise, we would have proven the identity. Would it be possible to show this perhaps?

Comment: Second last line should read "... for $n=1, 4, 7, 11, \cdots $..."

Comment: @hypergeometric: It is nice idear! Thanks for looked!

Answer (score 12):

This is slightly indirect way of approaching the problem but just for sake of variety I am adding a new approach.

Making the substitution $k \mapsto n-j$,

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^{n-k}\binom{n+k}{n-k}x^{2k} = \sum_{j = 0}^{n} (-1)^{j}\binom{2n-j}{j}x^{2n-2j} = U_{2n}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$$

where, $U_{n}(x)$ is the Chebyshev Polynomial of the second kind. See [**here**](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1075490/129017) for an elementary proof of the rightmost equality.

Making the substitution $x = 2\cos \theta$, we may write the above expresion as:

$$U_{2n}\left(\frac{2\cos \theta}{2}\right) = \frac{\sin (2n+1)\theta}{\sin \theta}$$

Thus, $$\begin{align}\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{(-1)^{n-k}}{2k+1}\binom{n+k}{n-k} &= \int_0^1 \sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^{n-k}\binom{n+k}{n-k}x^{2k} \,\mathrm{d}x \\
&= \int_0^1 U_{2n}(x/2)\,\mathrm{d}x\\&= 2\int_{\pi/3}^{\pi/2} \sin (2n+1)\theta \,\mathrm{d}\theta \\
&= \left.-2\frac{\cos (2n+1)\theta}{2n+1}\right\vert_{\pi/3}^{\pi/2}\\
&= \frac{2}{2n+1}\cos \left(\frac{(2n+1)\pi}{3}\right)\end{align}$$

as required.

Comment: The last line has a sign error (perhaps you switched the limits from the line above). Otherwise, the idea is very nice. (+1)

Comment: @robjohn Thanks! :-) fixed the mistake with the sign.

Comment: (+1) since Chebyshev polynomials are more famous than Fibonacci ones.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I realized later that what I have done just differs by a factor of $i$, writing $(ix)$ in place of $x$ in Fibonacci Polynomial. I feel stupid :P